# Android Studio: Add notification count on tabs

Tags: android

How can i add badges on tabs so that users can track where tab had a notification so far I tried using `viewbadger` but codes are deprecated. And I tried this code.

```
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ICONS[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ICONS[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ICONS[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(ICONS[3]);
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);

//        m_tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(R.id.tabs1);
//        badge1 = new BadgeView(this, m_tabs, 0);
//        badge1.setText("5");
//        badge1.show();

//            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
//            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(OwnerTabs.this);
//            tab.setCustomView(imageView);
//            badge = new BadgeView(OwnerTabs.this, imageView);
```

Can somebody give me other ways to do so? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
code for onCreateOptionMenu.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_navigation, menu);

            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
            menuItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(4, android.R.color.transparent));


            return true;
        }

        private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noitification_count, null);
            view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

            if (count == 0) {
                View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.badge_layout1);
                counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge_notification_1);
                textView.setText("" + count);
            }

            view.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        }
```

notification_count.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/badge_layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_item_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_dollar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badge_notification_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout_item_count"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

put your shape file

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/green"/>
</shape>
```

its work for me. and you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799985/want-perfect-circle-for-notification-count).

Comment: i think you have to use 'tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(4, android.R.color.transparent));'. try this.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try this. I'll come back if i have questions :)